# Correct usage of NonEmptyStringParam in Dropwizard

Tags: java-8, dropwizard

I'm a newbee using Dropwizard and I'm following the tutorial in the website to create the hello world application. Can anyone please explain to me how to use NonEmptyStringParam to print something like "Hello, stranger!" if no parameter is provided to sayHello?

The following is my Resource code and it outputs:

`{"id":1,"content":"Hello, Optional[Stranger]!"}`

instead of

`{"id":1,"content":"Hello, Stranger!"}`

```
public class HelloWorldResource {
    private final String template;
    private final NonEmptyStringParam defaultName;
    private final AtomicLong counter;

    public HelloWorldResource(String template, String defaultName) {
        this.template = template;
        this.defaultName = new NonEmptyStringParam(defaultName);
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    public Saying sayHello(@QueryParam("name") Optional<NonEmptyStringParam> name) {
        final String value = String.format(template, name.orElse(defaultName));
        return new Saying(counter.incrementAndGet(), value);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wrap the `NonEmptyStringParam` with `Optional<>`. See the [testcase from the Dropwizard source](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/params/NonEmptyStringParamProviderTest.java#L48-L55).
Also remove the wrap of `defaultName` with `NonEmptyStringParam` in the constructor method.